# Orchard CMS: Cannot install modules from dashboard gallery

Tags: orchardcms

All of this was done on my local machine.

I installed Orchard from within WebMatrix a few days ago (Orchard v 1.3.9)

I installed the Contoso Theme

I followed the instructions for the HelloWorld module and the Simple Commerce Module , and they work fine: this entailed adding modules from the gallery from within the dashboard: like the Code Generation Module

Today, if I try to install any modules from the gallery from within the dashboard, I get the following message with a red background:

Package installation failed.

There was an error installing the requested package. This can happen if the server does not have write access to the '~/Modules' or '~/Themes' folder of the web site. If the site is running in shared hosted environement, adding write access to these folders sometimes needs to be done manually through the Hoster control panel. Once Themes and Modules have been installed, it is recommended to remove write access to these folders.

The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

I go into the Requests section of Web Matrix, and it shows the request to grab the Messaging module:
it says

302.0 Object Moved
Path C:/Users/Rick/Documents/My Web Sites/RickHodder/Packaging/PackagingServices/InstallGallery

GET http://localhost:36700/Packaging/PackagingServices/InstallGallery?packageId=Orchard.Module.Messaging&version=1.3.0&sourceId=1&redirectUrl=%2FPackaging%2FGallery%2FModules

Did the orchard project change the place where the gallery pulls from?
I didnt make any changes to the machine, and I looked in the windows update log, and see nothing that might have change rights.

Any ideas?

Comment: The head of the orchard project just emailed and said that they did change the location but put in permanent redirects that should be automatically followed. Maybe it hasnt propagated to my isp yet - I'll try tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "fixed" it but have no idea what really fixed it - I created a new Orchard site from webmatrix, ran the site, then opened the broken site in web matrix and ran the site, and I was able to see the gallery, and even able to install a module.

Maybe some cache somewhere was updated.

Comment: I had the same problem as you.  Bertrand and Noah have the correct answer: the new feedservice address must be used, and *the casing must be correct 'FeedService.svc'*

Comment: Thanks Brent, but the feed name was properly cased. I dont know what the real problem is, but I know that several people are experiencing this issue, without even changing the feed name, which was supposedly not necessary because they set up the feed to use a 302 (permanent redirect).

Answer (score 8):

I think the issue is that the URL is case-sensitive.  I had the exact same issue with the new package URL that Bertrand supplied.  However, changing the case feedservice.svc to FeedService.svc fixed this.  With this gallery URL, I'm now able to install modules from the dashboard:

http://packages.orchardproject.net/FeedService.svc

Answer (score 3):

**Updated Feed URL:**

This answers here should be updated, as the new Gallery Feed URL has changed:

**NEW Feed URL:** https://orchardgallery.azurewebsites.net/api/FeedService

**Steps to update older Orchard versions**

Go Admin > Settings > Gallery, then click the "Add Feed" button on the top right to paste the new feed URL.

You can then **delete** the old one feed URL:

**OLD Feed URL:** http://packages.orchardproject.net/FeedService.svc

The red error should disappear now from the Modules Gallery section.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you may want to try is to set the gallery feed address in the site settings to the new URL, which is if I remember correctly http://packages.orchardproject.net/feedservice.svc

Comment: Thanks Bertrand, I will try that out - currently in Settings\Gallery it is http://orchardproject.net/gallery/server/FeedService.svc.

Comment: When I set the gallery feed to that address, and then go to Modules and click the gallery tab, the gallery cannot load and I get message: 

Error loading extensions from gallery source 'Default'. Error processing response stream. Server failed with following message: An error occurred while processing this request..
 
Error processing response stream. Server failed with following message: An error occurred while processing this request.
 
Any ideas?

Comment: From the address, I get the following, which makes me think that no packages are in the list:  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
- <service xml:base="http://packages.orchardproject.net/FeedService.svc/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2007/app">
- <workspace>
  <atom:title>Default</atom:title> 
- <collection href="Packages">
  <atom:title>Packages</atom:title> 
  </collection>
- <collection href="Screenshots">
  <atom:title>Screenshots</atom:title> 
  </collection>
  </workspace>
  </service>

Comment: No, if you want the list of packages, add /Packages after that address.

Comment: It must be a cache issue of sorts. weird. Might be worth filing a bug so we can investigate further.

Comment: Updating the gallery url to http://packages.orchardproject.net/FeedService.svc worked for me! (be sure to capitalize--doesn't work otherwise)

Comment: I must have a correct gallery url and am able to get the url content in the browser, however I am getting same error as Rick both when I install from gallery and from my computer nupkg package. Did also add the permissions for the Modules & Themes folder on my machine with no luck.

Comment: If all else fails, you can always manually unzip the package, find the module’s folder inside and just copy it into the modules folder in your Orchard web site. There’s a good chance this would fail with a new error however, pointing you to what the real problem with that module was from the start...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I just fixed it :-) Open the folder "Modules" and "Themes" in the Windows explorer, right-click, Properties > Security > Edit... Set all possible rights to all users you use (for me it was System, MyUsername, Administrators and one other). Then download (not install) the desired theme/module, go back to the dashboard, choose "Themes"/"Modules" > Install from your computer... and it works :-)
Hope I could help!

Comment: Hi Linda, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it didnt fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this problem and here is what I did:

1. Go to Programs & Features
2. List item
3. Click on Turn Windows Features on or off
4. Click on Internet Information Services

Now, I went through and turned on everything for **Web Management Tools** and **World Wide Web Services** because I was missing several items. I didn't have time to try this one at a time to figure out what one actually did it; but after turning these on; the error had finally went away and I could install themes.

I did this in addition to:

1. Updating the gallery URL to be
   http://packages.orchardproject.net/FeedService.svc/
2. Granting everyone full permissions to the directory

Hopefully this will help in the future for anyone else facing this error.  If anyone has a chance to pin point down what exact options should be selected in the World Wide Web Services that would be good!

Thanks,

Flea

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I finally discovered that the issue was due to a custom theme I've developed. Everything else in Orchard worked perfectly except for module installation.

It seems that, for some reason, the formatting of the `Version` field in my `Theme.txt` file was preventing the Orchard 1.8 from being able to install modules from the gallery. I've no idea how the `Theme.txt` causes the module installation to fail but I know that when the Version field has the value `1`, the module installation fails with:

> Package installation failed: There was an error installing the
>   requested package. This can happen if the server does not have write
>   access to the '~/Modules' or '~/Themes' folder of the web site. If the
>   site is running in shared hosted environement, adding write access to
>   these folders sometimes needs to be done manually through the Hoster
>   control panel. Once Themes and Modules have been installed, it is
>   recommended to remove write access to these folders.

When I set the `Version` value to `1.0.0`, modules could be installed without problem.